# High CPU usage from Node.js when running vue-cli-service serve

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli-3

The CPU usage by Node goes well over 100% when I run my npm script, which is using `vue-cli-service serve`.
How can I debug this issue?

I'm working on a Mac, Node installed through nvm. Node version: 10.16, npm version: 6.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was caused by the polling option.

Removing `poll: true` from the `watchOptions` in the webpack config  - fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Removing it from where?

Comment: From watchOptions in my webpack configuration. See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptions

Comment: In my case on Win10 - in file `vue.config.js` it was in `devServer -> watchOptions -> poll: true`. Setting it to false removed cpu eating (while watching files works).

Answer (score 19):

Installing the `fsevents` module on MacOSX will help reduce the CPU usage.

`npm install fsevents -g`

`npm rebuild fsevents`

Comment: This worked for me with this problem, but could you explain why? Happy to upvote with a bit of context!

Comment: @Ollywood Webpack suffers for high CPU usage if fsevents is not utilized. See this github issue. github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/701

Comment: At first this didn't work for me, due to an error in building node-gyp as I don't have XCode. After installing the Xcode Command Line Tools via `xcode-select --install` which was quick, fsevents installed and the high CPU usage dropped immediately.

Comment: had to run `npm rebuild fsevents` after migrating to an M1 machine.

Answer (score 0):

i use linux in virtualbox for dev purpose, and i have shared folder from windows host to linux guest. and my my vue project is stored in my hdd and shared with vbox.

so that i have to used `{devServer: watchOptions: {poll: true}}` in my vue.config.js for hot reload to works. this was causing the high cpu usage problem.

so i put my code in guest hdd and set poll:false and problem has gone.

hope someone find this helpfull.